# Convert All String Values of an Object to Lowercase Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to take an array of objects that contains string and numeric values and convert all string values to lowercase. I don't know ahead of time what specific values my array objects will have, so I just want to first check if an object within the array contains a string, and then make that string lowercase. When I run the following, I get an error.

```js
let data = [{
    userId: 1234567890,
    errorId: 957,
    userCategory: "Category",
    userAge: 18,
    userType: "Standard"
  },
  {
    userId: 1234567890,
    errorId: 583,
    userCategory: "Second",
    userAge: 28,
    userType: "Superuser"
  },
  {
    userId: 1234567890,
    errorId: 823,
    userCategory: "Third",
    userAge: 38,
    userType: "Admin"
  }
]

let newData = data.map(x => x.toLowerCase());

console.log(newData) //data is not a function
```

Comment: Loop over the properties in each object with `Object.keys(x).forEach()`

Comment: Did you mean `data.map(...)`?

Comment: Using some of the latest toys: `data = data.map(obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([name, value]) => [name, typeof value === "string" ? value.toLocaleLowerCase() : value])));` More on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript). (I just couldn't resist posting it, sorry all. :-) Also voted to close as too broad.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.map()` to iterate over the array, you can't just use the array itself as a function.

You can then use `Object.entries(x).map()` to iterate of the keys and values of the object, and lowercase the string values. A new object can then be created using `Object.fromEntries()`.

```js
let data = [{
    userId: 1234567890,
    errorId: 957,
    userCategory: "Category",
    userAge: 18,
    userType: "Standard"
  },
  {
    userId: 1234567890,
    errorId: 583,
    userCategory: "Second",
    userAge: 28,
    userType: "Superuser"
  },
  {
    userId: 1234567890,
    errorId: 823,
    userCategory: "Third",
    userAge: 38,
    userType: "Admin"
  }
]

let newData = data.map(x => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x).map(
  ([key, value]) => [key, typeof value == 'string' ? value.toLowerCase() : value])));

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.map` is not needed here (some other answers suggest this) since you are not changing what the objects themselves are, only their properties.

Iterate over the array, changing the objects.

```js
let data = [{
  userId: 1234567890,
  errorId: 957,
  userCategory: "Category",
  userAge: 18,
  userType: "Standard"
}, {
  userId: 1234567890,
  errorId: 583,
  userCategory: "Second",
  userAge: 28,
  userType: "Superuser"
}, {
  userId: 1234567890,
  errorId: 823,
  userCategory: "Third",
  userAge: 38,
  userType: "Admin"
}];

for (let obj of data) { // for each loop, iterates over values
  for (let key in obj) { // iterates over the keys
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
      obj[key] = obj[key].toLowerCase();
    }
  }
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate over the object keys and check the `typeof` it's value - if it's a string then call `toLowerCase` on it, otherwise just return the original data. For example:

```js
let data = [{
    userId: 1234567890,
    errorId: 957,
    userCategory: "Category",
    userAge: 18,
    userType: "Standard"
  },
  {
    userId: 1234567890,
    errorId: 583,
    userCategory: "Second",
    userAge: 28,
    userType: "Superuser"
  },
  {
    userId: 1234567890,
    errorId: 823,
    userCategory: "Third",
    userAge: 38,
    userType: "Admin"
  }
]

const newData = data.map(el => {
  const newEl = {};

  for (const key in el) {
    newEl[key] = typeof el[key] === typeof '' ? el[key].toLowerCase() : el[key]
  }

  return newEl;
});

console.log(newData);
```